# Suddenly Ubuntu Studio's native global theme is removed

Tags: ubuntu-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArH3G.jpg)
The 3 UBUNTUSTUDIO themes in the image disappear.

I was setting up ubuntu studio for a few days.
but suddenly
Ubuntu Studio's native global theme will disappear from the settings screen and the standard Plasma desktop will be used.

Even the splash screen is now that curt dot icon.

The cause is unknown.

just,
I booted up the PC, cycled it on and off a few times, and noticed that the power switch was touching the case.

But I don't think this is the reason.

Of course you can fix it by reinstalling the OS, but I don't think it will solve it.

I want to go back to the cool Ubuntu desktop.

Below, Japanese translation

画像内の 3 つの UBUNTUSTUDIO テーマが消えます。

数日間、ubuntuスタジオをセットアップしていました。
しかし突然
Ubuntu Studio のネイティブ グローバル テーマは設定画面から消え、標準の Plasma デスクトップが使用されます。

スプラッシュ画面も、あの素っ気ないドットアイコンになりました。

原因は不明です。

ただ、
PC を起動し、数回オンとオフを繰り返したところ、電源スイッチがケースに触れていることに気づきました。

しかし、これが理由ではないと思います。

もちろんOSを再インストールすれば直りますが、それでは解決しないと思います。

クールな Ubuntu デスクトップに戻りたいです。

Comment: I found the cause.
UbuntuStudio related packages are automatically removed due to packages installed to build Tenacity Audio.
If you re-insert the deleted package with the apt install command, the environment will be restored.

Below, Japanese translation

原因が分かりました。
Tenacity Audio を構築するためにインストールされたパッケージのため、UbuntuStudio 関連のパッケージは自動的に削除されます。
削除したパッケージをapt installコマンドで再挿入すると環境が復元されます。